# Leaflet (OSM) on Cordova Android throwing mixed content message

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, openstreetmap

Due to switching to HTTPS in my Cordova app, I've started getting a mixed-content message when trying to load the map tiles from Open Street Maps through Leaflet.

My URL for OSM is: `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, and I have the following in my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*.tile.openstreetmap.org/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*.tile.openstreetmap.org/*"/>
```

Is there anything I can do in Cordova to allow mixed content? And even though I'm setting https in the url for OSM, it keeps going back to http.